# while updating property for 1 object its updating properties for rest of the same objects in list

Tags: c#, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
     public class Employee
      {
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private int reqId;

    public int ReqId
    {
        get { return reqId; }
        set { reqId = value; }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Employee> d1 = new Dictionary<int, Employee>();
        d1.Add(1, new Employee { Name="Amol" });           

        List<Employee> lstEmps = new List<Employee>();
        Employee emp=null;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            emp = null;
            emp = d1[1];                
            emp.ReqId = i;
            lstEmps.Add(emp);
        }
    }
}
```

}

So while updating ReqId  its getting updated for all objects present in the list.In the last iteration it is assigning same value to all the objects in list.Is it happening because of getting it from dictionary or any reference issue.
I want to give unique id to ReqId.

Comment: No. You have only one instance of class with multiple references.
emp = d1[1]; does not create a new instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you created a single object, and kept adding it to your list in a loop.

Your dictionary `d1` contains only one object - the object added here:

```
d1.Add(1, new Employee { Name="Amol" });
```

Pulling it twice and assigning to `emp` does not make a copy of it - you add the same object to `lstEmp`.

In order to fix this problem you need to make a copy of `Employee` object, rather than reusing it:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    lstEmps.Add(new Employee {
        Name = d1[1]
    ,   ReqId = i
    });
}
```

Comment: but i have a real time scenario where this will be the case and to distinguish i have reqId field. Is there any way by which i can achieve it?

Comment: @AmolKadam You need to create a new object. Currently, when you set `ReqId` on `emp`, the value of `d1[1].ReqId` changes as well, because you have only one object.

Comment: thanks for the solution ! So I have to remap every field of employee object.Is there any way by which we can create copy of an object?

Comment: @AmolKadam A better approach is to create an additional "copying constructor" like this: `Employee(Employee other) {this.Name = other.Name; /*and s on */}` Then you'd be able to write `emp = new Employee(d1[1]) {ReqId = i}` and the copying would be encapsulated within the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is due to reference issue. Class is a reference type. Also you are not creating objects of the class employee. You are referring to the same dictionary item again and again.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Employee> d1 = new Dictionary<int, Employee>();
        d1.Add(1, new Employee { Name = "Amol" });

        List<Employee> lstEmps = new List<Employee>();
        Employee emp = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            emp = new Employee();
            emp.Name = d1[1].Name;
            emp.ReqId = i;
            lstEmps.Add(emp);
        }
    }
```